# null pointer exception in response.sendredirect

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Hi i faced a scenario where using

```
response.sendRedirect(url);
```

throws null pointer and

```
                RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(url);
                view.forward(request, response);
```

working fine.

My code is

```
            if (session==null)
      {

        String url = "/HelloWorldNewSession";
        //Throws null pointer if session is null
        //response.sendRedirect(url);
        RequestDispatcher view = 
        request.getRequestDispatcher(url);
        view.forward(request, response);
    }
```

I disabled cookies in my browser and i m creating a new session.

Question is does response.sendRedirect requires a session to redirect ?

Comment: can you post the error stacktrace? I don't think `response.sendRedirect` requires a session though (well, maybe i'm wrong, but let see where you got the npe first ;) )

Comment: your are forward the request to which one jsp or servlet or html ?

Comment: i am forwarding request to servlet on a same JVM.

Comment: give the url pattern of the servlet.

Comment: Please show stacktrace. But as a wild guess, I would say that if `response.sendRedirect(url)` throws a NullPointerException, either `response` or `url` is null. And I can confirm that `sendRedirect` does not need a valid session.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the `url` is requested to be effective .And `/HelloWorldNewSession` is not it.So it returns a null pointer.

Comment: It is throwing error 500 internal server error not 404

Comment: I have seen the same problem in "the use of uninitialized variable" elsewhere.Maybe you should list the whole error.

Comment: @Seven the `NullPointerException` is thrown when you have a reference to a null variable and uninitialized variable is one of those cases but the problem here is that the `sendRedirect` of the response to the following `url` is `null`.

Comment: i know. What i mean is Can problems in  other places before here cause this problem?

Comment: No I think the problem is related to the `response.sendRedirect(url);` which is `null`.

Comment: um..that means you need to debug it step by step here.Oversee  variables .Look at it can not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in [**Difference between SendRedirect() and Forward() in JSP Servlet**](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/09/sendredirect-forward-jsp-servlet.html):

**requestDispatcher.forward():**

> This method is used to pass the request to another resource for further processing within the same server, another resource could be any servlet, jsp page any kind of file.This process is taken care by web container when we call forward method request is sent to another resource without the client being informed, which resource will handle the request it has been mention on requestDispatcher object which we can get by two ways either using ServletContext or Request. This is also called server side redirect.
>
> When we use forward method request is transfered to other resource within the same server for further processing.

**response.sendRedirect():**

> This method is used to redirect client request to some other location for further processing ,the new location is available on different server or different context.our web container handle this and transfer the request using  browser ,and this request is visible in browser as a new request. Some time this is also called as client side redirect.
>
> In case of sendRedirect request is transfered to another resource to different domain or different server for futher processing.

So the reason why `sendRedirect()` throws a `NullPointerException` in your case is that you are using it to redirect to an url in the same server which gives `null` because the `url` is **unreachable** and the `response` can't be redirected to this `url`.